# How to get data property from dbpedia?

Tags: sparql, semantics, semantic-web, dbpedia, sparqlwrapper

I am trying to use SPARQL to query data on Manchester United FC wikipedia page using dbpedia (which can be found here [http://dbpedia.org/page/Manchester_United_F.C.]).

I have successfully accessed dbo and dbp properties but I can't seem to access properties like "is dbp:winners of". Querying this property always results in an empty set. What am I doing wrong? Here's my query:

```
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?club ?loc ?league ?trophy WHERE {
?club a db:SoccerClub.
?club dbpedia2:location ?loc.
?club db:league ?league.
?club dbpedia2:winners ?trophy
FILTER regex(str(?club), "Manchester")
}
```

Comment: the expression `"is PROPERTY of"` means the inverse relationship, i.e. you have to change subject and object in the triple pattern: `?trophy dbpedia2:winners ?club`.

Comment: @AKSW Thank you so much. This worked.